# How to create a sharepoint Page on Office 365 using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, office365

On my Visual Studio 2012 software I need to create new web page for my Office 365 SharePoint as a Landing Page for my site. The Page has to contain some logic related to the SharePoint which is to be developed in Visual Studio itself.
The Question is what is the best way to achieve this, what should the project type be (should it be ASP.NET empty Web Application, if so what else would be required to setup) and How to pakage it and deploy on the Cloud (Office 365 account).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create App(Now called as SharePoint Add-In), then use the app-catalog to deploy and Install app on SharePoint office 365 site.

Below are some reference which will be helpful to you:

1. [Buliding SharePoint Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/fp179930.aspx)
2. [Add a custom page and style to a SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt148589.aspx)
3. [Use the App Catalog to make custom business apps available for your SharePoint Online environment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-App-Catalog-to-make-custom-business-apps-available-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-0b6ab336-8b83-423f-a06b-bcc52861cba0)

Hope this helps